# creating a table using jade and underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, pug

I want to iterate through a JSON object array and create a table using underscore and jade 
but my jade template is throwing me the following error and I haven't been able to find any resources to fix it.

```
  Error: /home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/views/dashboard/index.jade:69
    67|               script(type="text/template" ,id="data-table")
    68|                 <% _.each(article,function(article){ %> 
  > 69|                     tr
    70|                       td  <%= article.ProjectName %>                              
    71|                       td  <%= article.Date %>                              
    72|                       td  <%= article.Status %>                               

unexpected token "indent"
    at Parser.parseExpr (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:252:15)
    at Parser.block (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:707:25)
    at Parser.tag (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:816:24)
    at Parser.parseTag (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:737:17)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:211:21)
    at Parser.block (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:707:25)
    at Parser.tag (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:816:24)
    at Parser.parseTag (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:737:17)
    at Parser.parseExpr (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:211:21)
    at Parser.block (/home/kseguy/node_projects/prwrite/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:707:25)
```

How can I debug the issue ? I have already tried converting indentation to tabs and spaces using sublime text but so far no success.

Here is my jade template

```
tbody      
          script(type="text/template" ,id="data-table")
            <% _.each(article,function(article){ %> 
             tr
              td  <%= article.ProjectName %>                              
              td  <%= article.Date %>                              
              td  <%= article.Status %>                               
              td  <%= article.Url %>
            <% }); %>
```

Comment: You must act as if the <.. text is not there, so the tr should be at the same indent level as the script.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the script was a template, then the <% lines must be at the same level as the tr. In either case nothing can be a child of a "comment line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work since jade treats things starting with < as regular text. But you must be careful as it is not possible for them to have children, so lines beneath them can not be further indented.

Here is a jade test with normal comments, that you could then replace with underscore

```
 // http://jsfiddle.net/smwpvngc/2/
 <template>
 script  
   <!-- each -->  
   tr
     td <!-- col1 -->
     td <!-- col2 -->
     td <!-- col3 -->
   <!-- close each -->
 </template>
```

Output:

```
<script> 
<!-- each --> <tr><td><!-- col1 --></td><td><!-- col2 --></td>
<td><!-- col3 --></td></tr><!-- close each --></script>
```

If I add an additional space before the tr, I also get an indent error as jade does not know how to fill a raw entry with children.

Comment: Thanks, it was a little hard to understand at first but I get it now.

Comment: @Bazinga777 Independent layers can be very powerful, but are pretty complex if you don't need independent stages. Normally I would just use one template format per template, and pass around compiled templates like any other function. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/smwpvngc/3/